# How can I find specific badges assigned to users in specific country/continent?

Tags: support, badges, search

Is there any search technique so that I can find **Any specific badge assigned to number of users in a specific country/continent**.

I saw a SO user mentioned in his profile: "Single user in the continent to earn *xxx* badge."

Comment: I guess that user simply went through the list of people with that badge. Seeing as you can enter any location in your user profile (including made up ones) building a query is going to be near impossible.

Comment: use the [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) and build your query, but keep in mind what @Pekka웃 mentioned

Answer (score 1):

The following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/698668?location=Netherlands) tries to make the best out of the data available:

```sql
select b.name
     , Choose(b.class,'Gold', 'Silver','Bronze') [class]
    --  , b.tagbased
     , count(*) [number of users]
from users u
inner join badges b on b.userid = u.id
where u.location = ##location:string## collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_ci_ai
-- and b.name = ##badge:string## collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_ci_ai
and tagbased = 0
group by b.name, b.class 
order by count(*)
```

When run today this will be the result for some European country:

[image: result]

Keep in mind SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday.